# When was the last time a Chainlink data feed was updated? Are Chainlink data feeds running?

Tags: chainlink

I'm looking to know both:

1. When was the last [Chainlink Data Feed](https://data.chain.link/) update?
2. Are the Chainlink Data Feeds running right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this programmatically or manually:

## Manually

You can see the last update, and if the feeds are running by:

1. Going to the specific [Chainlink data feed you are curious about](https://docs.chain.link/docs/reference-contracts/)
2. Going to the address of the data feed and checking it out in a block explorer like Etherscan. (The docs will offer a link to Etherscan for you)

[image: etherscan_chainlink_data_feed]

3. Going to the `Contract` tab -> `Read Contract` and clicking the `aggregator`

[image: aggregator]

4. In that contract, look at the most recent update.

[image: recent_update]

## Programatically:

In your solidity code, just return `timeStamp` from your `latestRoundData` call. Here are the [docs for reference](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/).

```
function getLatestTime() public view returns (uint) {
        (
            uint80 roundID, 
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return timeStamp;
    }
```